# How to give variable of object-2 the same value as a variable in object-1?

Tags: java

**Language:**
Java.

**Aim:**
give variable name from object rooms[] (class: Room) the same value as variable nameGuest from object guest1 (class: Guest).

**problem:**
this doesn't work

```
 void printRooms(){
  for(int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++){
    rooms[i].roomNr = ""+(i+1);
     for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
    a = guest1.getName();
    rooms[i].name = a;
  }//end for
}//end for
}//end void
```

**Reviewing:**
I've tried rooms[i].name = guest1.nameGuest. That did not work. Making a method getName to return nameGuest didn't work either. Same goes for making a pit-stop variable a to store the value.
I'm new to inter-class coding and am currently trying to read more about how to do it on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/ and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm But it's not working out.

**Question:**
How do you give object2.variable value to object1.variable
In this case, hotel must have a method printRooms that gives room[i] a number and the name(s) of the guest(s).

Here's my full code:

```
public class Hotel2 {
    Guest[] guest;
    Room[] rooms;
    String a;

    void execute() {
        rooms = new Room[10];
        Guest guest1 = new Guest("Alain");
        Guest guest2 = new Guest("Jantje");

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            rooms[i] = new Room(guest1);
        }

        //2 guests in 1 room
        rooms[9] = new Room(new Guest[]{guest1, guest2});
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rooms));

        printRooms();

    }

    void printRooms() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
            rooms[i].roomNr = "" + (i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                a = guest1.getName();
                rooms[i].name = a;
            }//end for
        }//end for
    }//end void

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Hotel2()).execute();
    }
}

class Room {
    Guest[] guests;
    String roomNr;
    String name;

    //1 guest constructor
    Room(Guest g) {
        guests = new Guest[1];
        guests[0] = g;
    }

    //several guests constructor
    Room(Guest[] g) {
        guests = g;
    }

}

class Guest {
    String nameGuest;

    Guest(String n) {
        nameGuest = n;
        System.out.println(nameGuest);
    }

    String getName() {
        return nameGuest;
    }
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong? If the data and types are correct there's zero reason you can't assign one variable the value of another.

Comment: Appologies for the indentation. I copied the code directly (from dr. Java) and had to add spaces so that Stackoverflow would detect it as code.
As for what goes wrong:

1 error found:
File: C:\Users\s150951\TUE Web Science jaar 1\Programming (E)\Hotel2.java  [line: 31]
Error: guest1 cannot be resolved

This is what it keeps telling me. But I can't figure out what's wrong with guest1. No matter what I try some part of what I use to get the value of nameGuest "can't be resolved"

Comment: There is indeed a problem with your "guest1" variable. It is declared locally in your "execute()" method and then you attempt to use it on "printRooms()". You should declare "guest1" (and maybe guest2 as well) as attributes in your class, the same way you do with your "guest" and "rooms"  arrays.

Comment: Ah, i see now. Very sharp, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to understand what you're asking.

Your problem seems to be with this code:

> ```
> void printRooms() {
>     for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
>         rooms[i].roomNr = "" + (i + 1);
>         for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
>             a = guest1.getName();
>             //  ^^^^^^ Compiler error: cannot resolve symbol "guest1"
>             rooms[i].name = a;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Notice the comment `^^^^^` I put in there.
The code doesn't compile,
because the variable `guest1` is undefined.
It's not defined inside the method,
and it's not defined as a field of the class.

If your intention is to overwrite each room's name using the first guest's name, this would be it:

```
void printRooms() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
        rooms[i].roomNr = "" + (i + 1);
        rooms[i].name = room.guests[0].getName();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't make sense for a method called `printRooms`,
as it prints nothing.

But I hope that based on this you'll figure out how to do what you really want to do.

Comment: This appears to do the job. Thank you, I think I'll be able to find the flaw in my old code and carry on.

I agree that printRooms is an odd name for the method but it's not my call. I expect to be instructed to print something later.

Appologies if my question was unclear. I intended to make it as clear as I could and I now intend to try even harder next time. I suspect my explanations are hamstrung by my inexperience but I'm working all hours of the day to fix that.

Thank you for your help.